# Need Help connecting WD My Cloud NAS to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, cloud, nas

I recently purchased the 2TB WD My Cloud NAS, and now I realize that it doesn't have Ubuntu support and can not figure out how to make it connect. I found this,
 http://cocoaallocinit.com/2014/01/04/wd-my-cloud-nas-on-ubuntu/ 
but it doesn't make sense.

```
showmount -e IP Address of Device>
```

It is talking about the My Cloud right? Where do I find the IP address for that?

Comment: Navigate your browser to http://192.168.1.1/ Your device might appear there, and you can grab the IP from that.

Comment: You should be able to look at your router's admin panel to find the NAS IP.

Comment: Also notice this comment on the same blog "To watch my files in WD NAS 2 TB I open Nautilus. Then choose Network and connect to server. Then type smb:// e.g. smb://192.168.1.55" You should be able to just navigate to the NAS and then bookmark the location.

Comment: you can take a look at this article :
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dulio-denis/wd-my-cloud-nas-on-ubuntu_b_5121961.html

Comment: If you are using `mount` and are having trouble, try using the `-o tcp` flag with it.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same MyCloud.  Its pretty simple if you have an idea of what you are doing.

Log into the MyCloud management console.

Assign a STATIC IP Address.

Enable NFS service in MYCloud.

On ubuntu client open Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

Close Terminal

Open Nautilus and click 'connect to server'.  Shown in picture below on bottom left.
[image]

A dialog box will show up that says 'connect to server' like in the picture below:
[image]

Now type nfs://hostname or static ip

SIDENOTE:  Isn't ironic how WD uses linux for the firmware/operation of the MyCloud but refuses to support it as a client or even provide documentation for open source clients! Cheapskate HYPOCRITES!

That's one way of connecting to your MyCloud!

Answer (score 2):

When I plug in my WD My Cloud Ubuntu instantly recognizes it when you open File Manager and click on Browse Network (at the left pane). You can also access the web interface by typing "wdmycloud.local" in a browser's address bar.

Comment: This solution relies on AFP, so that must be enabled.