# Can't connect to WD MyCloud Ubuntu Gnome 16.10

Tags: nas

So I just upgraded my ubuntu Gnome install from 16.04 to 16.10 and for some reason I can nolonger connect to my WD MyCloud. When I go to + Other Locations > WDMyCloud in Nautilus/Files and get this error.

```
 Unable to access location
 Error resolving 'WDMyCloud.local': Name or service not known
```

I followed the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469368/need-help-connecting-wd-my-cloud-nas-to-14-04) and ran `sudo apt-get install nfs-common` in my terminal but that did not help.

Can anyone help me with this? Should I down grade back to Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?